# The controller for path ... was not found or does not implement IController

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am writing an application using ASP.NET MVC 5 using c#. I have a need to add a global menu on the upper right hand side of the application. I was advised [other SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38530830/how-can-i-create-a-global-menu-for-my-application-whith-its-items-pulled-from-a) to use action with `ChildActionOnly` attribute.

So here is what I have done.

I created a BaseController like this

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult ClientsMenu()
    {
        using (SomeContext db = new SomeContext())
        {
            return PartialView(db.Database.SqlQuery<Client>("SELECT * FROM clients").ToList());
        }
    }

}
```

Then I inherited all my controllers from `BaseController` like so

```
public class TasksController : BaseController
{

    public ActionResult Index(int ClientId)
    {
        ...
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Show(int SurveyId)
    {
        ...
        return View();
    }

}
```

To render the `ClientsMenu` in my layout I added the following code

```
@Html.Action("ClientsMenu", "Menus")
```

Now when I run my application I get the following error

```
The controller for path '/Tasks/Index' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

When I remove `@Html.Action("ClientsMenu", "Menus")` from the layout everything works fine but the global menu does not show of course.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

**Updated**
Here is what I have done after the feedback I got from the comments below

```
public class TasksController : Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult ClientsMenu()
    {
        using (SomeContext db = new SomeContext())
        {
            return PartialView(db.Database.SqlQuery<Client>("SELECT * FROM clients").ToList());
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Index(int ClientId)
    {
        ...
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Show(int SurveyId)
    {
        ...
        return View();
    }

}
```

but still the same error

Comment: Can you post your RouteConfig.cs?

Comment: Take `CleintMenus` Action out of the base controller and put it into its own controller. like the example you linked to. Based on what you've showed. you don't have a `MenusContoller` which is what `@Html.Action("ClientsMenu", "Menus")` is looking for.

Comment: @Nkosi That did not work

Comment: Update your question with what you tried.

Comment: I just did. either way, the whole Idea of inheritance the `BaseController` is to prevent me from having to copy my code into every controller

Comment: @Jaylen. You don't need it in every controller. Put it in its own controller and call that controller from the Views. Which is what the answer you linked to showed. You are not following that answer. Did you read the article linked to by the answer you are following?

Comment: Can you show the content of `ClientsMenu.cshtml` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take `ClientMenus` Action out of the `BaseController` and put it into its own controller `MenusController`. You can then call that controller from your Views.

```
@Html.Action("ClientsMenu", "Menus")
```

In your example you don't have a `MenusContoller` which is what `@Html.Action("ClientsMenu", "Menus")` is looking for.

The [Phil Haacked - Html.RenderAction and Html.Action](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx/) article linked to by the other post provided a good example for you to follow.